# AWS MQTT Connection Status showing Reconnecting

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I have run this example https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSub.

I have already replaced all of the credentials. 
But I am getting status connecting and reconnecting continously.

Comment: Hi Did you find any solution . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate how you set up your Android App so that we can duplicate your problem?

Basically, there are two ways of authenticating your Android App connecting to IoT. One is through Cognito identity pool, the other is through X.509 certificates. If you are using Cognito Pool ID to connect to IoT, there is a few things you can check. First, could you check if you enable enable access to unauthenticated identities by editing your identity pool? Secondly, could you also check if you attach correct Policy e.g. AWSIoTFullAcess to your Unauthenticated Role? 
If you are using TLS certificates, could you check if you attach correct IoT Policy on that certificate? And also, please make sure you associate the correct region in you App which should be same as your IoT region. You can always enable CloudWatch or subscribe life cycle events to monitor IoT log or status.